# Bundling directory of images in app

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile

Wondered if someone could help please:)

Titanium 5.5.0 sdk
Appcelerator 4.7.1

I need to be able to bundle a bunch of images in my iOS app and then get a directoryListing so the user can pick an image out of it.

In an older app I did this by placing my image directory in:

assets/iphone/[folder here]

and used this code:

---

```
var path = Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + '[nameoffolderhere]';

var imgDirectory = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(path);

var imagesArray = imgDirectory.getDirectoryListing();
```

---

and it worked. For some reason when I'm building a NEW app this no longer works. Indeed even the older app running under the latest SDK still finds the images. BUT using the exact same folder structure in a new app and it can't find the directory.

Could someone throw a light on the best place to place these directories so I can receive a directory listing and get to the images please?

thanks very much in advance

ade

---

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `<use-app-thinning>true</use-app-thinning>` enabled in your tiapp.xml? If so, images are bundles with the asset-catalog are not accessible as files.

You should probably try to place them in `app/platform/ios` then, to copy them as resources instead of assets or disable app-thinning if you don't explicitly need it.